# Progress bar with intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, progress

I am trying to create a progress bar with steps and a play/pause button.

I am having trouble with creating the play/pause button but the case is that onload progress bar should not be filling, only after pressing the play button.

The second case I can't figure out is when the progress bar is running if the pause button is pressed it should stop at the end of the interval in which he currently is.

For example, if we press play and the progress bar starts filling up if the pause button is pressed between the starting point and 1st interval, it should stop at the end of the 1st interval, if the pause button is pressed between 1st interval and 2nd interval, it should continue to fill to the end of the 2nd interval etc.

I hope I made it clear.

```js
const checkpoints = [
  {
    perc: 25, 
    label: "25%\n<b>2018</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 35, 
    label: "35%\n<b>2019</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 45,
    label: "45%\n<b>2020</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 55,
    label: "55%\n<b>2021</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 100,
    label: "100%\n<b>2022</b>"
  }
];
const step = 1;
const timeInterval = 100;
const playLabel = 'PLAY';
const pauseLabel = 'PAUSE';

//on document ready..
$(document).ready(()=>{
  
  //shows checkpoints under the progressbar
  for(checkpoint of checkpoints){
    $('#rulers')
      .append(`<p class='ruler' style='width:${checkpoint.perc}%;'>${checkpoint.label}</p>`);
  }
        
  //attaches click event handler to #playpause button
  $('#playpause').on('click', (event)=>{ toggleButton( $(event.currentTarget) ) });
});

function toggleButton(playPauseButton){
  const status = $(playPauseButton).attr('data-status');  
  //if the button was in pause state (and having the Play label)
  if (status == "pausing"){        
    $(playPauseButton)        
      //toggles it to status 'playing'
      .attr('data-status', 'playing')
      //toggles it to "Pause" label
      .text(pauseLabel);    
    //begins incrementing the progressbar
    const intervals = checkpoints.map(cp => cp.perc);
    setProgressWithCheckpoints(intervals, step, timeInterval);
  }
  //if the button was in playing state (and having the Pause label)
  else if(status == 'playing'){
    $(playPauseButton)
      //toggles it to status 'pausing'
      .attr('data-status', 'pausing')
      //toggles it to "Play" label
      .text(playLabel);
    //if the progressbar is still running to complete its task,
    if( isStillRunning() === true ){
      //sets the playpause button as disabled so that you can't click it
      $(playPauseButton).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
}

//set the progressbar at perc
function setProgress(perc){    
  $(".progress .progress-bar")
    .css('width', `${perc}%`)
    .attr('aria-valuenow', perc)
  $(".progress .progress-bar span")
    .text(`${perc}%`);    
}

//get progressbar %
function getProgress(){
  const valueNow = $(".progress .progress-bar")
                    .attr('aria-valuenow');
  return parseInt(valueNow);
}

//return true/false if the progress is still running
function isStillRunning(){
  if ( $('#playpause').attr('data-stillrunning') == 'yes' )
    return true;
  return false;
}

//sets the state stillrunning to yes
function setStillRunning(){
  $('#playpause').attr('data-stillrunning', 'yes');
}

//sets the state stillrunning to no and enables the button (in case it was disabled)
function setNotStillRunning(){
  $('#playpause')
    .attr('data-stillrunning', 'no')
    .prop('disabled', false);
    
   if ( $('#playpause').attr('data-status') == 'playing' )
    toggleButton(  $('#playpause') );
}
```

```css
.progress{  
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 0;
}

.progress{  
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar{
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 600;  
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.progress-bar span{
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#rulers {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
}

#rulers .ruler{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border-right: solid 2px darkgray;
  padding-right: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#playpause {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#playpause:disabled{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div
    class="progress-bar"
    role="progressbar"
    aria-valuenow="0"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"
    style="width: 0%;background: green;">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rulers">
</div>

<button id="playpause" data-status="pausing">PLAY</button>
```

Here is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/Wildfactor/pen/WNMwbEP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of a progress bar having some defined checkpoints.

The defined checkpoints hold the percentage value of each one and its label to show in the ruler.

After pressing the play button, the button label toggles to "pause" and the progress bar will begin advancing. If the pause button gets clicked, the progress will advance until next checkpoint and stop.

If the progress arrives to 100% and the pause button wasn't still pressed, the progress will stop and the button will revert to pause state.

When the progress is running until next checkpoint and the button was pressed to pause, it won't be possible to press the play button until the progressbar will reach the checkpoint.

```js
const checkpoints = [
  {
    perc: 25, 
    label: "25%\n<b>2018</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 35, 
    label: "35%\n<b>2019</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 45,
    label: "45%\n<b>2020</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 55,
    label: "55%\n<b>2021</b>"
  },
  {
    perc: 100,
    label: "100%\n<b>2022</b>"
  }
];
const step = 1;
const timeInterval = 100;
const playLabel = 'PLAY';
const pauseLabel = 'PAUSE';

//on document ready..
$(document).ready(()=>{
  
  //shows checkpoints under the progressbar
  for(checkpoint of checkpoints){
    $('#rulers')
      .append(`<p class='ruler' style='width:${checkpoint.perc}%;'>${checkpoint.label}</p>`);
  }
        
  //attaches click event handler to #playpause button
  $('#playpause').on('click', (event)=>{ toggleButton( $(event.currentTarget) ) });
});

function toggleButton(playPauseButton){
  const status = $(playPauseButton).attr('data-status');  
  //if the button was in pause state (and having the Play label)
  if (status == "pausing"){        
    $(playPauseButton)        
      //toggles it to status 'playing'
      .attr('data-status', 'playing')
      //toggles it to "Pause" label
      .text(pauseLabel);    
    //begins incrementing the progressbar
    const intervals = checkpoints.map(cp => cp.perc);
    setProgressWithCheckpoints(intervals, step, timeInterval);
  }
  //if the button was in playing state (and having the Pause label)
  else if(status == 'playing'){
    $(playPauseButton)
      //toggles it to status 'pausing'
      .attr('data-status', 'pausing')
      //toggles it to "Play" label
      .text(playLabel);
    //if the progressbar is still running to complete its task,
    if( isStillRunning() === true ){
      //sets the playpause button as disabled so that you can't click it
      $(playPauseButton).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
}

//set the progressbar at perc
function setProgress(perc){    
  $(".progress .progress-bar")
    .css('width', `${perc}%`)
    .attr('aria-valuenow', perc)
  $(".progress .progress-bar span")
    .text(`${perc}%`);    
}

//get progressbar %
function getProgress(){
  const valueNow = $(".progress .progress-bar")
                    .attr('aria-valuenow');
  return parseInt(valueNow);
}

//return true/false if the progress is still running
function isStillRunning(){
  if ( $('#playpause').attr('data-stillrunning') == 'yes' )
    return true;
  return false;
}

//sets the state stillrunning to yes
function setStillRunning(){
  $('#playpause').attr('data-stillrunning', 'yes');
}

//sets the state stillrunning to no and enables the button (in case it was disabled)
function setNotStillRunning(){
  $('#playpause')
    .attr('data-stillrunning', 'no')
    .prop('disabled', false);
    
   if ( $('#playpause').attr('data-status') == 'playing' )
    toggleButton(  $('#playpause') );
}

function setProgressWithCheckpoints(intervals, step, ms){
  
   setStillRunning();
  
  const valueNow = getProgress();     
  const nextIntervals =
    intervals.filter((interval) => interval > valueNow);      
  const nextInterval =
    (nextIntervals.length > 0) ? nextIntervals[0] : null;

  const newValue = Math.min(nextInterval, valueNow+step);    
  setProgress(newValue);

  const playpauseStatus = $('#playpause').attr('data-status');

  //if progress got to 100% OR
  //   nextInterval got reached while the play button is in pause state
  if(newValue >= 100 || (nextInterval == newValue && playpauseStatus == 'pausing')){
     //ends the calling and set the button as notStillRunning
     setNotStillRunning();
  }
  //else
  else
    //call again the progress function
    setTimeout(()=>{setProgressWithCheckpoints(intervals, step, ms)}, ms);  
}
```

```css
.progress{  
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 0;
}

.progress{  
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;  
  height: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  width: 100%;
}

.progress-bar{
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 600;  
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.progress-bar span{
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#rulers {
  position: relative;
  height: 3em;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
}

#rulers .ruler{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border-right: solid 2px darkgray;
  padding-right: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#playpause {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#playpause:disabled{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div
    class="progress-bar"
    role="progressbar"
    aria-valuenow="0"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100"
    style="width: 0%;background: green;">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rulers">
</div>

<button id="playpause" data-status="pausing">PLAY</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed, one more question, I am trying to read the data from the JSON file, is it possible to get the variables of the checkpoint from the JSON object instead of constants.

Thank you very much.

Comment: of course it's possible... but luckily only because I went with the dynamic checkpoints on my own initiative. You just need to populate the value passed to the function `setProgressWithCheckpoints` with the array you have. Anyway consider that there are some assumptions in my code that will produce odd beahviours when clicking pause/play repeatedly. The button shouldn't be able to play if there's already a job running until next checkpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much Diego, your answer was really helpful, I am marking this question as resolved.

Thank you once again.

Comment: you are welcome. I hope you'll be able to use it as is... and that the intervals strategy will scale correctly. If you have problems in the next days try to comment here and probably I'll catch the notification

Comment: I edited my answer to include your latest requirements and to improve its consistency. Now the button always behaves correctly according to any condition and the rulers show in a very granular fashion the information about the checkpoints. Plus everything is much better styled. I think there's nothing left. It could just be better factored to scale on an arbitrary amount of progressbar+rulers+button in the same page.

Comment: Diego, thank you very much, you really helped me a lot, I appreciate it very much. This is exactly what I needed. From your example I have learned a lot, I really appreciate every comment in the code it really helped me a lot to understand the functionality and structure. Once again, huge thanks.

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering you once again, I have one more question, I am trying to figure it out but really can't. How can I only display the label of which checkpoint the progress bar is passing through.

For example: If the progress bar passed first interval to display the values only of the first interval above it's checkpoint, when it passes the 2nd interval to display only value of 2nd interval above it's checkpoint. I Hope I made it clear. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hey Diego, I have managed to figure out the label display per active checkpoint, If you have a moment can you assist me on how to manipulate the progress bar to go backwards, basically if we are looping through the values in the object, if the first percentage is 35, and the next to that is 15, how to achieve from progress bar to go backwards from 35 to 15 percent?